# What's wrong with this javascript? myArray is not defined

Tags: javascript

I would like to try search/filter JSON table data with javascript.
What's wrong with this code?

```
async function callApi(){
    const res = await fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users/')
    const users = await res.json();

    var myArray = []
    myArray = users.data
    buildTable(myArray)
    console.log(myArray)
}
callApi();
buildTable(myArray);
```

everything is fine so far, until ↓

```
const search = document.getElementById('search-input');
search.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
    let value = e
    console.log(value)
    let data = filterTable(value , myArray)    // this line throws the error
    buildTable(data)
} );


function filterTable(value , data){
    let filterData = []
    for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
        value = value.toLowerCase()
        let name = data[i].name.toLowerCase()

        if (name.includes(value)){
            filterData.push(data[i])
        }
    }
    return filterData;
}
```

↓
This is the error I am getting:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: myArray is not defined`

```
function buildTable(data){
    let table = document.getElementById('myTable')
    table.innerHTML = ''
    for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
        let row = `<tr>
            <td>${data[i].first_name}</td>
            <td>${data[i].last_name}</td>
            <td>${data[i].email}</td>
            </tr>` 
    table.innerHTML += row
    }
}
```

** Update ↓

after I define variables globally, I got different errors

```
function filterTable(value , data){
    let filterData = []
    for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
        value = value.toLowerCase()  //Uncaught TypeError: value.toLowerCase is not a function 
        let name = data[i].name.toLowerCase()

        if (name.includes(value)){
            filterData.push(data[i])
        }
    }
    return filterData;
}
```

if I turn that errors part into

```
value = value.toString().toLowerCase()
let name = data[i].name.toString().toLowerCase()
```

then I got `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined"`

is there any concept I missing out?

Comment: what is inside value?

Comment: the value is any words user want to search and by typing in like "m", user can get the result matched with "m"

Answer (score 3):

Your array is defined inside a function, it´s not global, so you can´t access to it from anoter function:

```
async function callApi(){
    const res = await fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users/')
    const users = await res.json();

    var myArray = []        // array is here
    myArray = users.data
    buildTable(myArray)
    console.log(myArray)
}
```

Should be like this:

```
var myArray = []        // array is here

async function callApi(){
    const res = await fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users/')
    const users = await res.json();

    myArray = users.data
    buildTable(myArray)
    console.log(myArray)
}
```

Comment: thanks for helping me out!  I got another problems, still don't know how to sort fetched data properly.

Comment: You said <then I got "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined" >. In which line, when you try to convert 'value' or 'data[i].name'?

Comment: I've figured it out! I misunderstood the usage of second parameter in addEventListener, thanks again for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

you need to define your variables globaly

Add this on top of your script

```js
//variables
var myArray = []
```